# NHibernate could not insert

Tags: nhibernate

Hi i Create empty local database called baza.sdf

My Domain

```
namespace mapowanie.Domain {
    public class User
    {
        public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
        public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
    } }
```

My Mapping hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="mapowanie"
                   namespace="mapowanie.Domain">

  <class name="User">
    <id name="Id" generator="guid" />
    <property name="FirstName" type="string" />
    <property name="LastName" type="string"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSqlCeDialect</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlServerCeDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=D:\aaawypociny\mapowanie\mapowanie\baza.sdf</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

UserRepo

```
class UserRepository
    {
        public void Add(User newUser)
        {
            using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
            {
                using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    session.Save(newUser);
                    transaction.Commit();

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

At transaction.Commit when i try to add

```
UserRepository repo = new UserRepository();
var ja = new User { FirstName = "Name", LastName = "Surname" };
repo.Add(ja);
```

VS give me

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException' occurred in NHibernate.dll
>
> Additional information: could not insert:
>   [mapowanie.Domain.User#8cafd9e5-0eda-4ccc-ba4a-f8935b68dfdc][SQL:
>   INSERT INTO User (FirstName, LastName, Id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)]

what i can do wrong?

Comment: what does the inner exception say?

Comment: System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ProcessResults(Int32 hr)    w System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.CompileQueryPlan()    w System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavio r, String method, ResultSetOptions options)    w System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()    w NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.ExecuteNonQuery(IDbCommand cmd)    w NHibernate.AdoNet.NonBatchingBatcher.AddToBatch(IExpectation expectation)    w NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Insert(Object id, Objec t[] fields, Boolean[] notNull, Int32 j, SqlCommandI

Comment: Could you also post a script definition of your table structure

Comment: Hibernate generate: 
    drop table User

    create table User (
        Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER not null,
       FirstName NVARCHAR(255) null,
       LastName NVARCHAR(255) null,
       primary key (Id)
    )

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the table name, I think "`User`" is a suspect reserved word., try to define in the hbm:

```
<class name="User" table="`User`">
```

note the **``** around user, this notify NHibernate to escape the table name. To use issue queries by hand ( ie not through NHibernate ) escape the name manually, for example:

```
create table [User] (
    Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER not null,
....
```

Comment: unfortunately nothing new :(

Comment: or maybe... with file should have build action: embedded resources?

Comment: @user1638121 hbm must have Embedded Resource. But you have since the query is issued do Database. I bet on the reserved word. Try at least by renaming te table Users.

Answer (score 0):

Felice Pollano was right regarding reserved word "User", please rename the table and try again.
I faced same issue renaming solved my issue.

Also please verify table name you passed is correct, I didnt renamed that, I struggled for it..

`<class name="User1" table="User1" lazy="false">`

Answer (score 0):

In some cases where the actual exception message isn't being shown, you could try:

- checking that all the fields are nullable in the db so that if some required values aren't being supplied, you can see what is going through, you can always change that back later
- check that your field lengths are large enough to hold the data that is being sent, otherwise you'll get a `data will be truncated` message in the guise of a `could not insert` message